# How to Calculate Sum of each Columns Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Controller**

This is Controller Page.

```
public function index() {
$data = array(
     'year' => $this->year_model->list_all(),
     'speces' => $this->speces_model->list_all(),
       );
          foreach ($data['year'] as $value):

                $temp = array();
                $temp['year_key'] = $value['year-range'];
                $temp['year_id'] = $value['id'];


                $temp['speces_key'] = array();
                foreach ($data['speces'] as $value1):

                    $temp['speces_key'][$value1['name']] = $this->db->get_where('expendituredata', array('spacesId' => $value1['id'], 'yearId' => $value['id']))->row_array();

                endforeach;
                $final_result[] = $temp;

            endforeach;
            $data['result'] = $final_result;
            $this->load->view('site/template', $data);
        }
```

**View**

This is View file.

```
 <table>
 <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Year Range</th>
        <?php foreach ($speces as $value): ?>
         <th> <?php echo $value['name']; ?></th>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
           </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
       <?php foreach ($result as $value): ?>
          <?php $sum = 0; ?>
           <tr>
              td><?php echo $value['year_key']; ?></td>

                <?php foreach ($value['speces_key'] as $key => $value2): ?>
                  <td><?php echo $value2['data']; ?></td>
                    <?php $sum+= $value2['data']; ?>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                <td><?php echo $sum; ?></td>
                </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0R39.jpg)

MY Question : How to Calculate Total in above screen shot.

so please view above screenshot and Calculatre total for all animal according to year.

Comment: Do it in SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this :

```
$select =  array(
                'table.col1',
                'table.col2',
                'table.COW+table.DOG+table.CAT+table.BIRD+table.ARV+table.CAMP as TOTAL'
               );  
$this->db->select($select); 
$this->db->from('expendituredata');   
$this->db->where(array('spacesId' => $value1['id'], 'yearId' => $value['id']));
$this->db->row_array();
```

Or use this simple SQL query

`select COW+DOG+CAT+BIRD+ARV+CAMP as TOTAL from table where col = 'val';`