# How to Calculate Sum of Columns Using Codeigniters

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Controller**

This is Controller Page.

```
public function index() {
$data = array(
     'year' => $this->year_model->list_all(),
     'speces' => $this->speces_model->list_all(),
       );
          foreach ($data['year'] as $value):

                $temp = array();
                $temp['year_key'] = $value['year-range'];
                $temp['year_id'] = $value['id'];


                $temp['speces_key'] = array();
                foreach ($data['speces'] as $value1):

                    $temp['speces_key'][$value1['name']] = $this->db->get_where('expendituredata', array('spacesId' => $value1['id'], 'yearId' => $value['id']))->row_array();

                endforeach;
                $final_result[] = $temp;

            endforeach;
            $data['result'] = $final_result;
            $this->load->view('site/template', $data);
        }
```

**Model**

```
public function list_all() {
        return $this->db->get('year')->result_array();
    }
```

**View**

This is View file.

```
 <table>
 <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Year Range</th>
        <?php foreach ($speces as $value): ?>
         <th> <?php echo $value['name']; ?></th>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
           </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
       <?php foreach ($result as $value): ?>
          <?php $sum = 0; ?>
           <tr>
              td><?php echo $value['year_key']; ?></td>

                <?php foreach ($value['speces_key'] as $key => $value2): ?>
                  <td><?php echo $value2['data']; ?></td>
                    <?php $sum+= $value2['data']; ?>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                <td><?php echo $sum; ?></td>
                </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

[image: ScreenShot of Table]

MY Question : How to Calculate sum(total) of Each Columns in above screen shot.

so please view above screenshot and Calculatre total for all animal according to year.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Calculate Sum of each Columns Using Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721790/how-to-calculate-sum-of-each-columns-using-codeigniter)

Comment: Where's your attempt at doing it? We're not here to write code for you, we're here to advise on existing code... you show me yours and I'll show you mine

Comment: Do it using MYSQL query... Use SUM function of mysql.

Comment: above screenshot in last row (total) display, my question  is sum of each columns(like cow,dog,cat,..) and sum display in last row (total)

Comment: how to use sum query in mycode?

Comment: You have to get result of sum and them group field from Active record in Codeigniter. 
 Visit This Link : [Get the result of SUM and group field from Active record in Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219709/get-the-result-of-sum-and-group-field-from-active-record-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Almost you have done Now you need only sum of all columns correct ?

Comment: you can use ROLLUP in mysql query  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68621/get-only-overall-summary-with-rollup-and-group-by-for-multiple-fields